# Hibernate, OneToMany, AnnotationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a problem with OneToMany annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESULT_HISTORY")
public class ResultHistoryImpl implements ResultHistory, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;


    @OneToMany
    private final Set<Game> games = new HashSet<>();


...

}
```

and class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GAME")
public class GameImpl implements Game, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    ...
}
```

I have more fields, setters/getters and constructors

I use spring and in my configuration files I have packagesToScan where I put packages of those classes

The problem is that I get org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

I read many topics on stackoverflow, so the problem isn't using org.hibernate.annotation etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you tried is not possible. `Game` is an interface and you cannot map an interface to DB, because hibernate does not know which implementation to use. But what you can do, is

1. use in all your entity classes the `GameImpl` class directly. I mean correct your `ResultHistoryImpl` class to this: `@OneToMany  private final Set<GameImpl> games = new HashSet<GameImpl>();`
2. If you want to have another abstraction, add an abstract class `AbstractGame implements Game` and annotate it with `@Entity` and use it instead of the `Game` interface.

Comment: I understand, but the problem is that Game implementation is in other module and I have access only to my colleges public api ( game interface) and I can't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Use @MappedSuperclass annotation on Game.

Comment: Is the exception the same?
I think you should try to combine the @MappedSuperclass and mappedBy as described by toni77 below.
Just to be clear: are using the @MappedSuperclass annotation on the Game interface like this:
`@MappedSuperclass
public interface Game {...}`

Answer (score 0):

For @OneToMany you have to provide a mappedBy property which points to a field name in the other class. In your case:

```
public class ResultHistoryImpl {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "resultHistory")
    private final Set<GameImpl> games = new HashSet<>();
}

public class GameImpl {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "result_history")
    private ResultHistoryImpl resultHistory;
}
```

Comment: Not work. Why you use ResultHistoryImpl instead of interface in GameImpl class ?

Comment: Andrei I. is right you cannot map interfaces to DB.